# Asp.Net MVC Web application with Web API?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, web-services

Actually I have 2 Web API service both returns the Json Data

**Web API service 1** : Used to login into the system. The system should allow the user to login if the status is "True" otherwise it should not allow the user to login into the system.                                                                            **Json result of Web API service 1 :[{"UserID":"1","Status":"True","Name":"ABC","Department":"IT"}]**

I can able to login with the service successfully. After login into the system i want to use the Web API 2 :

Web API Service 2 : It returns the data about the user.
**Json result of Web API service 2 :[{"UserID":"1","Task Done":"20","Task Pending":"10"}]**

**Login Model :**  [API 1]

```
    public class Login
{
   [Required(ErrorMessage = "Username is required")] // make the field required
    [Display(Name = "username")]  // Set the display name of the field
    public string username { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Password is required")]
    [Display(Name = "password")]
    public string password { get; set; }

    public string getname(string username) //This method check the user existence
    {
        string name = "";
        //string connString=
        // Read the connection string from the web.config file

        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Conn Details"))
        {

            conn.Open();
            // Calling scramble.NET dll to encode password 
            ScrambleNET.clScramble encrpt = new clScramble();
            string encrptedPassword = encrpt.EncryptText(password);
            string sql = "Execute splSystemLogin '" + username + "','" + encrptedPassword + "'";
            SqlDataAdapter adp = new SqlDataAdapter(sql, conn);
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            adp.Fill(ds);
            if (ds != null && ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                name = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Name"].ToString();
            }
            else
            {
                name = "";

            }


        }
        return name;


    }

}
```

**Controller :** [API 1]

```
public ActionResult Index(Login login)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid) // Check the model state for any validation errors
        {

            string uname = "";
            uname = login.username;
            string pword = "";
            pword = login.password;

            string url = "http://localhost:55506/api/Login/submit?username=" + uname + "&password=" + pword + "";
            System.Net.Http.HttpClient client = new System.Net.Http.HttpClient();
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri(url);
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
            HttpResponseMessage responseMessage = client.GetAsync(url).Result;

            var responseData = responseMessage.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
            JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<LoginResult>>(responseData);
            if (responseData.Contains("True"))
            {


                string name = "";
                Clinicnameinfo = login.getname(login.username);
                TempData["Name"] = Clinicnameinfo;
                ViewData["Name"] = Clinicnameinfo;



                return View("Show", login); // Return the "Show.cshtml" view if user is valid
            }
            else
            {
                ViewBag.Message = "Invalid Username or Password";
                return View(); //return the same view with message "Invalid Username or Password"
            }

        }
        else
        {
            return View();

        }
        return View();

    }
```

Now i can able to login into the system. But I stuck to get data from second API.

How can i compare the **Web API 2** with **Web API 1** after login to display the task details?

Thanks in advance !!! Looking to get the successful solution

Comment: please paste login methods of Web API 1 and Web API 2, So it may help to understand your problem.

Comment: added my code for your reference @ J-Mean

Answer (score 0):

Please try to use async and await when ever you are using asynchronous method calls. *Await means it will wait untill process is completed and after completion rest of code will be executed.*

In your code async method is called twice by client.GetAsync(url) and .Content.ReadAsStringAsync().

Modified your code :-

Controller : [API 1]

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Index(Login login)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid) // Check the model state for any validation errors
        {

            string uname = "";
            uname = login.username;
            string pword = "";
            pword = login.password;

            string url = "http://localhost:55506/api/Login/submit?username=" + uname + "&password=" + pword + "";
            System.Net.Http.HttpClient client = new System.Net.Http.HttpClient();
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri(url);
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
            HttpResponseMessage responseMessage = await client.GetAsync(url);

            var responseData = await responseMessage.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<LoginResult>>(responseData);
            if (responseData.Contains("True"))
            {


                string name = "";
                Clinicnameinfo = login.getname(login.username);
                TempData["Name"] = Clinicnameinfo;
                ViewData["Name"] = Clinicnameinfo;



                return View("Show", login); // Return the "Show.cshtml" view if user is valid
            }
            else
            {
                ViewBag.Message = "Invalid Username or Password";
                return View(); //return the same view with message "Invalid Username or Password"
            }

        }
        else
        {
            return View();

        }
        return View();

    }
```

Hope above will resolve your issue.

Comment: The above code works fine for me. i didn't use the second API URL.. i have two url's respectively.   URL 1:   string url = "http://localhost:55506/api/Login/submit?username=" + uname + "&password=" + pword + "";  URL 2: string DashBoardUrl = "http://localhost:55506/api/ClinicDashBoardInfo/submit?username=" + uname + "&password=" + pword + ""; Both url returns json result have a field called **UserId**. The First URL used to login .. The second url used to get the dashboard contents.  So how can i get the dashboard contents after login (only if the UserId of both URL Matches)

Comment: Likewise if you have forgot to added async and await in getting dashboard info. If this doesn't fixed then please paste the code to get dashboard info also, so i can help u out.